# Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is "How calculating are you?". I am simply wondering if under standard conventions of the English language, that this sentence ought to be perceived as being correct.

Comment: This might find a better home on ELU or ELL. I'll try an answer on that basis.

Answer (score 2):

It looks odd because the present participle of the verb "to calculate" is "calculating". The sentence works when it's being used as an adjective meaning "canny", "devious" or "shrewd".

As with much English ambiguity, there's opportunity for humour. If one character was working through some mathematics and said "I am calculating", the response "How calculating are you?" would be a joke.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is correct. In may not be considered formal English but it is Standard English.